# Where to move newly downloaded applications on Mountain Lion?

Tags: eclipse, macos, installation, osx-mountain-lion

I recently started using Mac, and I'm just getting accustomed to the way the folders are set up and how downloads work. I just downloaded a tar.gz for Eclipse, and I clicked the icon in the downloads to "unzip" it (not sure if unzip is the right term there). Now, where should I move the new Eclipse folder?? /usr/bin?? I want to make sure to keep my directories orderly in my new Mac, and want to do it the right way from the start :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's standard to put applications in the Applications folder. There's usually a shortcut to it  in Finder's sidebar.